# Redhat Linux 7 kerberos client is returning localhost in kerberos trace when it should be the fully qualified domain name

Tags: mongodb, kerberos

We have a RHEL7 Mongo server configured for kerberos authentication for Mongo connections. The Mongo instance start successfully which tells us the server principal keytab is defined correctly in AD and the KRB5_KTNAME value is correct. A kinit is successful for the id that we want to authenticate with, telling us the user keytab is valid. However when attempting to authenticate "Kerberos server not found" is returned. Looking at the kerberos trace it's reporting "localhost" instead of the fqdn. 
Mongo Support reviewed the DNS definitions and they are correct so referred us to Redhat support. The relevant message in the trace is:
Getting credentials userid@DOMAIN -> mongodb/localhost@ using ccache FILE: filename   (values changed to protect me)
Dpes anyone have an idea why localhost is in this message instead of the fqdn as it should be? Again DNS entries look to be correct. The "server not found" message is issued because localhost isn't defined to AD of course. 
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. When executing the shell on the same host as the Mongo server, you must include the --hostname parameter and not let it default. Kerberos uses the hostname value when sending requests to the KDC.